# Why did the community vote to reopen this question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, vote-to-close

[What are the differences between QA engineers and software engineers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/what-are-the-differences-between-qa-engineers-and-software-engineers)

I just don't think that this is constructive; and I feel like there's a small rant embedded in the question.

Comment: question you refer to looks like an almost perfect match for not constructive description: "As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion..."

Comment: Note that it hadn't been reopened: [it had never been closed prior to yesterday](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/87107/revisions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been closed as an exact duplicate.